# File upload kills rest services

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I have a Java REST app that uses Jersey 2.23.2.  Everything works fine, however, when I add a single service to upload a file, my entire app stops working.  The pages are services but none of the rest services work anymore.  Here is all I add to kill the entire app:

```
...
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataContentDisposition;
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataParam;
...
    @POST
    @Path("/upload")
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    public Response uploadFile(
            @FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream,
            @FormDataParam("fileinfo") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail) {
        return Response.status(200).build();

    }
```

I have no compile problems, and no warnings or messages when I start tomcat.  I have no idea what to do.  Thanks for the help!

Blake McBride

Comment: Also, I don't even call that service.  Just having it there kills the app.  If I put a breakpoint on the first line, it never gets there, so this method is never called.

Comment: I found this warning:  WARNING: No injection source found for a parameter of type public javax.ws.rs.core.Response com.xxx.services.MyService.uploadFile(java.io.InputStream,org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataContentDisposition) at index 0.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what fixed it:

1. add to the class that extends Application:

   returnValue.add(MultiPartFeature.class);
2. add the following jar's

jersey-media-multipart-2.23.2.jar

mimepull-1.9.7.jar

Now all works.

Blake